# How to filling DataGridview rows with embedded ComboBox with remained records only

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataGridView in VB.Net that has "ID" column with embedded CoboBox. then I fill each rows of DGV by selecting an "ID" from ComboBox. it is ok and my code works greate.
And what is the Problem:
I want to when the user open the embedded ComboBox, previus ID numbers that has been selected in other rows of DGV, unavailable in CoboBox item list.
I have to say that DataSource of CoboBox and DGV are same.
please help me. thanks in advance

Comment: Use two different data sources. Then, you can remove an item from the ComboBoxes `DataSource` when a selection is confirmed. Add back a selected ID if your users can remove/modify a Row or can change the ID after a selection.

Comment: @Jimi
Thanks for your reply. I try that before. If one record removed from datasource it removed from DGV field that has combobox also. Do you have another idea? Thanks

Comment: If you remove a record from the DGV data source and the same record is also removed from the ComboBox, then you definitely are not using two **different data sources**.

Comment: @Jimi
I have a separate copy of data-table for other data-source for Combo-box that embedded in DGV. When I select an item from combo-box i can fill all field of DGV according selected item easily but when i remove or filter selected item in previous record of DGV, removed item remove from DGV with Comb-box column also.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: you're removing an item - used to filter/create a record in the DGV - from a ComboBoxColumn data source, to avoid the duplication of records generated from the same filter (or similar case). When a row is deleted, the item previously removed from the ComboBox is missing and you haven't figured out a way to insert it back (it should be available again, since the row it filtered has been removed). If this is the case, post the proc that creates/assigns the data sources and the one that removes the rows (relevant to suggest a solution/workaround).